sed not work in github action with variables
My valid workflow file is :
env:
  TF_BACKEND_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.TF_BACKEND_BUCKET }}
  TF_BACKEND_KEY: ${{ secrets.TF_BACKEND_KEY }}
  TF_FILENAME: ${{ vars.TF_FILENAME }}
  TF_VAR_FILENAME: ${{ vars.TF_VAR_FILENAME }}


jobs:
  prepare_env:
    name: Prepare AWS Environment
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:  ${{ inputs.cloud_provider }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Apply Variables and Secrets
        working-directory: deploy/terraform-aws
        ## Set AK/SK and terraform s3 backend info
        run: |
          echo "current path is: $(pwd)"
          ls -l provision-kafka-aws.tf
          sed -i "s/TF_BACKEND_BUCKET/$TF_BACKEND_BUCKET/g" provision-kafka-aws.tf

My invalid workflow file is :
env:
  TF_BACKEND_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.TF_BACKEND_BUCKET }}
  TF_BACKEND_KEY: ${{ secrets.TF_BACKEND_KEY }}
  TF_FILENAME: ${{ vars.TF_FILENAME }}
  TF_VAR_FILENAME: ${{ vars.TF_VAR_FILENAME }}


jobs:
  prepare_env:
    name: Prepare AWS Environment
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:  ${{ inputs.cloud_provider }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Apply Variables and Secrets
        working-directory: deploy/terraform-aws
        ## Set AK/SK and terraform s3 backend info
        run: |
          echo "current path is: $(pwd)"
          ls -l provision-kafka-aws.tf
          sed -i "s/TF_BACKEND_BUCKET/$TF_BACKEND_BUCKET/g" $TF_VAR_FILENAME


The error output is :
sed: can't read provision-kafka-aws.tf
: No such file or directory

My question is : I am sure the file exists and ls is print out correcly. But github can't find file when use variables. How to solve this?

Use the GitHub Actions expressions syntax to reference your env variables:
env:
  TF_BACKEND_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.TF_BACKEND_BUCKET }}
  TF_BACKEND_KEY: ${{ secrets.TF_BACKEND_KEY }}
  TF_FILENAME: ${{ vars.TF_FILENAME }}
  TF_VAR_FILENAME: ${{ vars.TF_VAR_FILENAME }}

jobs:
  prepare_env:
    name: Prepare AWS Environment
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:  ${{ inputs.cloud_provider }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Apply Variables and Secrets
        working-directory: deploy/terraform-aws
        ## Set AK/SK and terraform s3 backend info
        run: |
          echo "current path is: $(pwd)"
          ls -l provision-kafka-aws.tf
          sed -i "s/${{ env.TF_BACKEND_BUCKET }}/${{ env.TF_BACKEND_BUCKET }}/g" ${{ env.TF_VAR_FILENAME }}


Thanks for your reply. I tried your way and the error still exists. TF_VAR_FILENAME's value is 'provision-kafka-aws.tf'
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker 12349 May 17 02:18 provision-kafka-aws.tf
sed: can't read provision-kafka-aws.tf
: No such file or directory


In which directory the provision-kafka-aws.tf file is located? The run script runs in the context of the working-directory: deploy/terraform-aws
